Web GL won't load suddenly. Is this a hardware issue? I just got a new laptop within the last month
screenshot of issueI've been following a threejs tutorial for a long time now and have never had this issue. Just got a new laptop about a month ago and I was following a tutorial and returned to finish and when I loaded it, I just got a white screen with the lilgui debuging program still functioning. It was working fine on this computer till just now. I'll include a screenshot of the screen with the js console errors. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on?
Here are the error messages in the console:
onContextCreationError @ chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367
Show 1 more frame
Show less
chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367 THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason:  Failed to create a WebGL2 context.
onContextCreationError @ chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367
Show 1 more frame
Show less
3chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367 THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason:  Could not create a WebGL context, VENDOR = 0xffff, DEVICE = 0xffff, GL_VENDOR = Google Inc. (Google), GL_RENDERER = ANGLE (Google, Vulkan 1.3.0 (SwiftShader Device (LLVM 10.0.0) (0x0000C0DE)), SwiftShader driver-5.0.0), GL_VERSION = 5.0.0, Sandboxed = yes, Optimus = no, AMD switchable = no, Reset notification strategy = 0x8252, ErrorMessage = BindToCurrentSequence failed: .
onContextCreationError @ chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367
Show 1 more frame
Show less
chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367 THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason:  Failed to create a WebGL2 context.
onContextCreationError @ chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367
Show 1 more frame
Show less
2chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367 THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason:  Could not create a WebGL context, VENDOR = 0xffff, DEVICE = 0xffff, GL_VENDOR = Google Inc. (Google), GL_RENDERER = ANGLE (Google, Vulkan 1.3.0 (SwiftShader Device (LLVM 10.0.0) (0x0000C0DE)), SwiftShader driver-5.0.0), GL_VERSION = 5.0.0, Sandboxed = yes, Optimus = no, AMD switchable = no, Reset notification strategy = 0x8252, ErrorMessage = BindToCurrentSequence failed: .
onContextCreationError @ chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17367
Show 1 more frame
Show less
chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17125 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.
WebGLRenderer @ chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17125
Show 1 more frame
Show less
chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17112 Uncaught Error: Error creating WebGL context.
    at new WebGLRenderer (chunk-6P5T4EWA.js?v=580916dd:17112:19)
    at script.js:161:18
injected.js:4 Retrieving "b5x-stateful-inline-icon" flag errored: timed out - falling back
qy @ injected.js:4
Show 1 more frame
Show less
script.js:140 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'renderer' before initialization
    at script.js:140:5

Tried restarting the computer, reinstalling the npm in the folder and no luck.

Okay I found the problem. I was trying to trouble shoot an unrealated issue with my browser (Brave), and in doing so I disabled 'Use graphics acceleration when available'. As soon as I enabled it, it worked correctly. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

Thanks for following up! It would be helpful to know what browser up front and trying different browsers to narrow it down
